# How to say "thank you for taking the time to read my email" in formal business Japanese

Tags: english-to-japanese, business-japanese

I am writing a cold-email template to engage with Japanese companies. I would like to say in formal Japanese:

> Thank you for taking the time to read my email

Comment: Can you add your own attempt?

Answer (score 2):

How about:

> お忙しい中目を通して頂き、ありがとうございます。